# Sincronizar Ajax

Tags: jquery

Tengo una aplicación en la cual descargo todos los datos cuando el usuario se loguea. Necesito que algunos datos se descarguen completos para ir al inicio de la aplicación, por que si no se recuperan todos pueden haber errores.

Ahora tengo *Ajax* de esta forma en donde bajo los datos:

```
    $.ajax({
      url: "cientes.php",
      dataType: "json"
    }).done(function() {
      .....
      .....
    });

$.ajax({
      url: "facturas.php",
      dataType: "json"
    }).done(function() {
      .....
      .....
    });
```

Cómo puedo asegurarme que que hasta que se descarguen los dos se ejecute el `callback` de inicio de la aplicación?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes aplicar JQuery Deferreds, te perite encadenar varios callback asincronos, en una línea de ejecución sincrona. En otras palabras, para el caso de tu pregunta, asegurarnos de que se llame el callback del inicio de tu aplicación, unicamente cuando se hayan realizado los dos ajax.

```
function successFunc() {
    console.log( "success!" );
    inicio();
}

function failureFunc() {
    console.log( "failure!" );
}

$.when(
    $.ajax( "clientes.php" ),
    $.ajax( "facturas.php" )
).then( successFunc, failureFunc );
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba agregando la opción [async](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) con valor *false* (por default es true) en cada petición Ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "cientes.php",
    dataType: "json",
    async:false
}).done(function() {
/*      .....
      ..... */
});


$.ajax({
    url: "facturas.php",
    dataType: "json",
    async:false
}).done(function() {
 /*      .....
      ..... */
});
```

otra opción desde luego es que dentro del **success**, **complete** o **done** (según como prefieras) realices el llamada de cada Ajax; por ejemplo:

*En vez de*

```
 $(function() {
    $.ajax({/* tus opciones link 1 */});
    $.ajax({/* tus opciones link 2 */});
});
```

*Sea*

```
 $(function() {
    $.ajax({/* tus opciones link 1 */})
        .done(function () {
            $.ajax({/* tus opciones link 2 */}).done(funcion() {/*....*/});
        });
});
```

Mas reciente he probado en algunas circunstancias **promise**, me ha resultado útil pero aún estoy en proceso de comprenderlo más a fondo.